# rails incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT in json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, utf-8, character-encoding

I use RestClient to retrieve a json string from a webservice via GET.
This works fine but as soon as there are Umlauts (ü) and other chars (e.g. ß) in the string, I get this error in my view

```
@output = RestClient.get 'https://myurl.com/api/v1/orders/53e0ae7f6630361c46060000', {:authorization => 'Token xxxxxx', :content_type => :json, :accept => :json}

<%= @output %>
```

=>

```
Encoding::CompatibilityError
incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT
```

any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved after adding this line

```
@output = @output.force_encoding('utf-8').encode
```